# erroe while configuring SLES 15 using autoinst.xml

Tags: opensuse, suse, sles

**Environment:** SLES 15 SP3

**Question:**

I got this error while installing  and configuring SLES 15 SP3 using autoinst.xml file(autoyast)

```
Internal error. Please report a bug report with logs. 
Run save_y2logs to get complete logs.

Caller: /mounts/mp_0001/usr/share/YaST2/lib/y2network/autoinst/ 
interfaces_reader.rb:131:in 'load_generic'

Details: undefined method 'values' for '':String
```

I cant figure out what this error is about. I searched in my xml file, there is no mention of `load_generic` or any other term in the error msg.
Could someone please help me out with this error. What's the reason for this error?

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion to run `save_y2logs`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Apologies for replying so late. I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @rayan then can you post your solution to help others in the same situation please?

Comment: like mentioned in the answer, it was a parsing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, I ran into this issue as well, and fixed it by removing <aliases/> from the <networking> -> <interfaces> -> <interface> section. This appears to be a change in the way this is parsed between 15-SP2 and 15-SP3 as it works on 15-SP2.